# NGINX: localhost redirecting to _

Tags: nginx, configuration, localhost, 301-redirect

*nginx version/1.18.0 (Ubuntu) — Ubuntu 22.04.01 LTS x86_64 kernel 6.0.8*

---

I've got a server (install specs above) that has multiple host names, is running nginx, and everything is working (including nginx, with redirects from http: to https:).

In fact, here's how I'm doing that in my default server:

```
listen 80 default_server;

listen 443 default_server ssl;
# force https-redirects
if ($scheme = http) {
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server_name _;
```

Here's the strange behavior:

| URL | Redirects to | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `http://mumblefrotz/` | `https://mumblefrotz/` | (works as expected) |
| `http://mumblefrotz.fullyqualified.com/` | `https://mumblefrotz.fullyqualified.com/` | (works as expected) |
| `http://127.0.0.1/` | `https://127.0.0.1/` | (works as expected) |
| `http://localhost/` | `https://_` | **FAILURE** |

**Why's it doing this?**  I suspect it has something to do with the [`server_name`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name) directive being taken literally, though am not quite certain why it only happens for `localhost`.

In looking at [this Stack Overflow suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454764/nginx-server-name-wildcard-or-catch-all/26383871#26383871), I attempted both of the following and still got the surprising underscore:

- `server_name ~.;`
- `server_name ~^(.+)$;`

My expectation is that `$host` is [the host name passed in the HTTP request](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables), with a virtual host picking it up if one has been defined and falling back to the default server definition if not.

From what I can tell `http://localhost/` is the only one that doesn't resolve properly.  I'd like to fix that.

Comment: Do you have for some reason added `_` to the hosts file on your server?

Answer (score 1):

There was no information on the question what client was used to make the request. As written in [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_host), `$host` variable contains:

> in this order of precedence: host name from the request line, or host name from the “Host” request header field, or the server name matching a request

Here, "request line" means the hostname after `GET` verb in HTTP request.

Second one means the `Host` header field.

Third one means the name configured in `server_name`.

In your case, I think the test client did a request that did not contain `Host` header. Therefore nginx used the `server_name` configuration for the content of `$host` variable.

Personally I just generate the HTTP -> HTTPS forward block for every virtual server, since I manage nginx configurations with Ansible. That way I can have a `return 404` vhost for all other host names I am not interested in.

But if you need to implement a common vhost for the redirects, you can use following approach:

```
map $http_host $redirect_host {
    ~ (^.+$) $http_host;
    default  example.com;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    ...

    if ($scheme = http) {
        return 301 https://$redirect_host$request_uri;
    }
}
```

This always uses the HTTP host header for redirect target, except when there is no `Host` header. In that case it uses `example.com` for the redirect target. You can assign your main domain name as the redirect target for example.